# iOS: open file with UIDocumentInteractionController and know what app opened the file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using `presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` to open documents in my app. The document interaction controller dismisses the menu automatically when the user selects an appropriate option. You can also dismiss it programmatically using the dismissMenuAnimated: method.
I would like to know the app used to open this document when dismiss the menu.

Comment: Have you looked at the UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate Protocol https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009305.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is called when the user chooses to open a document:

```
documentInteractionController:willBeginSendingToApplication:
```

on the UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate Protocol.

The "application" parameter is the bundle identifier of the application that is about to open the document. This value corresponds to the value in the CFBundleIdentifier key of the application’s Info.plist file.